# Query most recent status for each workcenter

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm have one table:

`Workcenter  | Date      |     Status
    ------------------------------
SLX83A  12/6/2016 3:11:20 PM    Running
SLX83B  12/6/2016 3:28:33 PM    Break/Lunch/Meeting
SLX83B  12/2/2016 10:11:37 AM   Breakdown
SLX83B  12/6/2016 3:28:29 PM    Running
SLX83B  12/6/2016 1:30:21 PM    Tool Change/Damage
SLX83B  12/1/2016 3:13:43 PM    Waiting On Crane
SLX83C  12/1/2016 8:10:56 AM    Break/Lunch/Meeting
SLX83C  11/27/2016 6:40:00 AM   Load/Unload Clamp Change`

I would like to output the most recent Status for each workcenter, such as:

`Workcenter  | Date      |     Status
    ------------------------------
SLX83A  12/6/2016 3:11:20 PM    Running
SLX83B  12/6/2016 3:28:33 PM    Break/Lunch/Meeting
SLX83C  12/1/2016 8:10:56 AM    Break/Lunch/Meeting`

I can get the most recent times with:

`SELECT [Current Status Query].[Workcenter ID], Max([Current Status Query].[MaxOfStart Date/Time]) AS [MaxOfMaxOfStart Date/Time]
FROM [Current Status Query]
GROUP BY [Current Status Query].[Workcenter ID];`

=

`Workcenter  | Date
    ------------------------------
SLX83A  12/6/2016 3:11:20 PM
SLX83B  12/6/2016 3:28:33 PM
SLX83C  12/1/2016 8:10:56 AM`

However I can't figure out how to get the Status' to "tag along."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
    Table t1
    LEFT JOIN Table t2
    ON t1.workcenter = t2.workcenter
    AND t1.Date < t2.Date
WHERE
    t2.workcenter IS NULL
```

You could do an `ANTI SELF JOIN`.  Basically `left join` the table to itself where the `t1.Date` is less than `t2.Date` to find the row that doesn't have a later row and then filter out the rows that do have matches.